# Is it true that there is no algorithm to approximate the least upper bound?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, algorithms, constructive-mathematics

I just read the following text below from Bishop's *Foundations of Contructive Analysis*, is it true that there is no such algorithm? The book is from 1967 - I don't know if someone managed to invent such algorithm until the present date.

> [image]

Comment: The integer sequence thing sounds like the Halting Problem to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me which format the inputs and outputs to $M$ would be, but suppose it's something like

**Input:** A description of a Turing machine $T$ that computes the sequence $x_k$ given $k$ as an input, together with a rational $q>0$, and (just to be generous) a formal proof that the $T$ actually produces a strictly increasing bounded sequence.

**Output:** A rational number that is within $q$ of the supremum of the $x_k$s.

*(Actually, reading the quote closer it seems like $M$ does this in two stages, first producing from $T$ a new Turing machine which again produces a stream of approximations. Never mind that, it doesn't change the argument).*

In that case it is much worse than "nobody expects that one will ever be found" -- it is **impossible** for such an $M$ to exist, because if it did we could use it to decide the halting problem. To wit, suppose we want to know whether the Turing machine $U$ halts. Then construct the machine $T$ to compute the following sequence:
$$ x_n = \begin{cases} 2-1/n & \text{if $U$ halts in fewer than $n$ steps} \\ 1-1/n & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Then $\sup x_n$ is $2$ if $U$ ever halts and $1$ otherwise (and it is trivial to supply proof that $x_n$ are strictly increasing and bounded by $2$), so if we ask $M$ to approximate $\sup x_n$ to within a tolerance $1/3$ it would implicitly tell us whether $U$ halts or not. And that is not possible, so $M$ can't exist.

---

(Note that it is essentially futile to want to remedy this by restricting the form in which $\{x_n\}$ is given as input to $M$, because the $\{x_n\}$ in this argument is *extremely* computable -- the sequences of its numerators and denominators are *primitive recursive* functions of $n$, and we certainly have to accept such specifications in anything that purports to handle general "constructively given" sequences of rationals.)

Comment: But isn't there another way to do such approximation? It baffles me that such algorithm can not exist. But I assume I have little knowledge in mathematics.

Comment: @Pristine: The argument given here is completely independent of HOW the approximation is arrived at. It simply says that IF you have SOME way to do it, THEN you can also do something that we know is impossible. If you try to come up with "another way", then the argument will still apply to that "other way".